# Shrepoint 2010 ribbon controls are disabled in my entire site

Tags: site-level-ribbon

I've created sharepoint site in 2010 with classic mode authentication. And add my custom site templates as site collection. I've permission as site collection administrators for my created site. But the ribbon controls are disabled in entire site (not to specific list/pages). Is there any permission/issues related to this?

Note: I've created one more site and added site collection using 'Team site' (default template). In that site, ribbon controls are in enabled mode (list/pages)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the below article helpful :-

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=spribbonvisibility

Check if this resolves the issue.